# Two apps sharing two CloudKit CKContainers: Need both UserRecordIDs

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have one app that uses it's own native CKContainer.   I am building a second app that uses the first app's native CKContainer and it's own native container as well.   I would like to access both container's userID using the function below.   However, I am only getting back the second app's native CKContainer UserID.   I am successfully using the public database of the first app in the second app.   I am only struggling when I try to perform a query specific to the user in the first app.

Does anyone know if this is possible and/or how to find a second CKContainer's userID?

```
func findUserRecordID() {
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (userID, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // obtain and store id
            if let userID = userID {

                SRData.sharedInstance.currentUser = userID




            }
        } else if error != nil {
            // handle errors

            print("There was an error" + "\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two `CKContainer` instances, one for each container. The two containers are not shared. Each has its own public database, its own private database, and its own users.

To create the other container, use:

```
CKContainer(containerIdentifier: "the-name-of-the-other-container")
```

Comment: Thanks.    That was it.

Comment: For everyone's reference:

Answer (score 0):

For everyones reference here is the code that worked.

CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.XXXX.YYYYY").fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (userID, error) in

```
        //

        if error == nil {

            // obtain and store id

            if let userID = userID {



                SRData.sharedInstance.currentV2User = userID



            }

        } else if error != nil {

            // handle error

            print("Error FindUserRecordID " + "\(error?.localizedDescription)")

        }



    }
```